# How to send an event/message to an unrelated game object in Unity/C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let's say I have two entities, a Player and an Enemy. Each of them would have its own C# script. On the Enemy, it has this basic health manager code:

```
[SerializeField] float health = 3;

public void TakeDamage(float damage)
{
    health -= damage;

    if (health <= 0) {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        // SOME EVENT HERE?
    }
}
```

What I want is for the Player to know he's killed the Enemy (as well as knowing which enemy he destroyed). However, I'm not sure how to do this. I've looked at a few approaches:

- Actions/delegates; they would require the Player to 'import' a public action/delegate from the Enemy (if I understand them correctly; I'm still new to C#), and I don't want a dependency between these two things... they're conceptually unrelated; I shouldn't have to 'import' from Enemy on the Player.
- Using Unity events (like the ones you configure in UI, for example button OnClick()); this won't work either, because both Player and Enemy might be instantiated at runtime, not pre-defined.

In my head I'm imagining the Player script would have something like this listening to events:

```
void OnEnemyDestroyed(GameObject enemy) { ...do things in reaction to enemy death here... }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: In order to listen to an event you will always need to know it yes! `UnityEvent` is basically the same .. it is just a wrapper around an event you can additionally also preconfigure vis the Inspector.. but if you want to attach a listener via code you again need to know the event

Answer (score 0):

For this specific situation my advice is using interface. For example:

```
public interface IUnit
{
    void OnEnemyKilled(IUnit enemy);
}
```

Both player and enemy script will implement this interface, the `TakeDamage` method also need to append a new parameter with the type `IUnit`.

```
class Enemy : IUnit
{
    public void TakeDamage(float damage, IUnit attacker = null)
    {
        health -= damage;

        if (health <= 0) {
            attacker?.OnEnemyKilled(this);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void OnEnemyKilled(IUnit enemy){}
}
```

This approach doesn't only solve the problem, the advantage is at some point, a single damage value is not enough, you may need information about who makes this attack, then you can add additional methods to the interface and execute them in `TakeDamage`.

Note that you'd better prepose the callback, so that in it you can keep accessing all the properties of the killed entity.

---

To answer the question in comment, there are many approaches to make sense, you can:

1. Pass null `TakeDamage(10f);` (Above method is updated)
2. Pass a default IUnit implementation

   ```
   class NotAUnit : IUnit
   {
       public static readonly NotAUnit Instance = new();
       public void OnEnemyKilled(IUnit enemy){}
   }

   TakeDamage(10f, NotAUnit.Instance);
   ```
3. An overloaded method. (As same as approach 1).

Comment: What if it doesn't make sense for one of the entities to be a Unit (and therefore inherit IUnit)? For example, an arkanoid-style ball and blocks situation

Comment: You can pass null, pass a default implementation, or create an overloaded method to take damage from balls or blocks. Update added.

Answer (score 0):

If it is about in general have a global event for listening on the destroying of objects you could have an additional component like

```
public class DestroyEvent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action<GameObject> OnDestroyed;

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        OnDestroyed?.Invoke(gameObject);
    }
}
```

So you could just globally attach a listener to

```
DestroyEvent.OnDestroyed += Listener;

...


private void Listener(GameObject destroyedObject)
{
    Debug.Log(destroyedObject);

    // e.g. list all attached components
    foreach(var component in destroyedObject.GetComponents<Component>())
    {
        Debug.Log(component.GetType());
    }
}
```

So as soon as an object has that component attached the moment it is destroyed you will receive the callback, regardless of whether it is spawned on runtime or even the component attached afterwards on runtime.

Have in mind that this is just a simple example - you will also get the event currently in case the scene is changed or you exit the app. But you can build on top of this and e.g. globally turn the event on and of with an additional flag etc